# How to stop this search function breaking when the user inserts a space

Tags: angular

I am brand new to Angular. I need to find out why this search function breaks when the user inserts a space. For example, currently the user could search for, say, a person's whole name. This function would allow the user to type until the end of the first name, but would break when the user inserts a space and then completely fail to detect the second name, even if the second name is present in the data.

I would appreciate any guidance enormously!

```
 private _filter(value: any): string[] {

        if (typeof value === 'string') {

            const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

            return this.clinics.filter((option: any) => {

                if (
                    option.email.includes(filterValue) ||
                    option.name.includes(filterValue) ||
                    option.surname.includes(filterValue) ||
                    option.account_name.includes(filterValue)) {

                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } else {
            const finalValue = [value];
            return finalValue;
        }
    }
```

thank you!

Comment: Can you describe the error you get? And maybe add the template/component logic connected to this piece of code?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly where you're code is breaking, could you do a little more debugging on where it is broken or add your console error? One thing you could do is add  `value = value.trim()` to remove any extra white spaces after your `typeof` check

Comment: Please show the code that triggered _filter method. Is it sniffing for the end of the word? If you type multiple words and end with a space does it reevaluate?

Answer (score 1):

the problem lies in logic

```
option.name.includes(filterValue) ||  option.surname.includes(filterValue)
```

here neither of name or surname include a space and the result is lost.
it should be something like this:

```
private _filter(value: any): string[] {

        if (typeof value === 'string') {

            const filterValues = value.toLowerCase().split(' ');

            return this.clinics.filter((option: any) => {
                return filterValues.every(filterValue => option.email.includes(filterValue) ||
                    option.name.includes(filterValue) ||
                    option.surname.includes(filterValue) ||
                    option.account_name.includes(filterValue))
            });
        } else {
            const finalValue = [value];
            return finalValue;
        }
    }
```